# pygithub search and read specific files

Tags: python, pygithub

I am using pyGithub to go through the files in the Github repository. The problem is, with this code `my_code.get_contents("")`, it goes through each and every file in all the folders and subfolders in the repo. Is there a way to make this code efficient. I am only interested in parsing the .csproj files and the packages.config files where they are found. But these files are scattered in multiple places.

```
from github import Github
import pathlib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def processFilesInGitRepo():
  while len(contents)>0:
    file_content = contents.pop(0)
    if file_content.type=='dir':
      contents.extend(my_code.get_contents(file_content.path))
    else :
       path=pathlib.Path(file_content.path)
       file_name=path.name
       extention=path.suffix
       if(file_name=='packages.config'):
          parseXMLInPackagesConfig(file_content.decoded_content.decode())
          
       if(extention=='.csproj'):
          parseXMLInCsProj(file_content.decoded_content.decode())  
  
       print(file_content)


my_git=Github("MyToken")


my_code=my_git.get_repo("BeclsAutomation/Echo65XPlus")
contents=my_code.get_contents("") #empty string i.e. ("") gives all the items in the Repository. But can I specify some kind of a search term here saying I need only .csproj and packages.config files.

processFilesInGitRepo()
```

Comment: It seems manually iterating over the files and check for specific pattern is the only way. The API that [`get_contents`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-repository-content) internally uses does not allow you to filter the files based on patterns.

Comment: I understand. Thank you. Do you happen to know any other libraries for instance pythonGit has these capabilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the file content of a specific file on a specific branch as well using pyGithub.

```
from github import Github

def connect_to_github():
    host = "https://github.com/<organisation-name>"
    token = "PAT TOKEN"
    github_instance = Github(token)
    return github_instance

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gl = connect_to_github()
    project = gl.get_repo("<organisation>/<project-name>")
    data = project.get_contents(path="<path of the file>",ref="<branch name>")
    content = data.decoded_content
    print(content.decode('utf-8'))
```